# How to make modifications to predefined functions in R?

Tags: r

A predefined function `A` can be modified using the function `fix(A)`. But what should be done to modify a predefined function `B` which is called inside predefined function `A` in R .

But I can see the function definition of function B  from got to function definition in the code tab.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `fix(B)`?

Comment: Yes but it didn't worked, just showed a pop up window showing            
   function() {}

Comment: Is B a function that exists in the environment in which A runs rather than in current environment?

Comment: You can't really change the behavior of functions that are not exported from packages (which is what it sounds like what is going on here). Can you be more specific and actually provide functions names and describe what you are trying to accomplish. There may be better ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Given the extra detail you provided in the comments, it appears that in this case the function `B` does not yet exist; from the help file under "Details" (accessible via `help("fix")`):

```
 The name supplied as ‘x’ need not exist as an R object, in which
 case a function with no arguments and an empty body is supplied
 for editing.
```

So, if I run `fix(B)` in a fresh R session (i.e., as my very first command with an empty global environment), I see this:

```
function()
{
}
```

which is what it sounds like you have experienced. As to *why* `A` is calling a function that does not exist, we can't say without more information.

#### Update (resolution in the comments)

As pointed out by [user2554330](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554330/user2554330) in the comments, this is a scoping issue (as confirmed by OP saying user2554330's addition fixed their issue), which could be addressed via

```
B <- get("B", envir = environment(A))
fix(B)
```

Comment: But I can see the code for the function by clicking  go to function definition from the code tab.

Comment: This sounds like a scope issue.  Your editor is looking at internal code; `fix()` doesn't do that.  You may need `B <- get("B", envir = environment(A))` to get the function before `fix(B)` will work on it.  Another issue is that `A` may still call the original `B` if you don't edit its environment as well as its body.